# Usage report AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, report, aws-api-gateway

I have deployed my API using AWS API Gateway. Each user is authorised to use different end points based on JWT.
I am searching a way to generate which user has send how many different types of API request. Searching AWS didn't give me any such service (i might be wrong). I would greatly appreciate if someone give some hint how to generate such reports?
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API Gateway allows you to enable access logging on a stage. The documentation briefly discusses how to specify the format of your access logs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html

This blog may provide a useful approach for making these logs searchable and analyzable: https://binx.io/blog/2018/11/17/elasticsearch-service-firehose-apigw-logs/

Comment: Hello, Thanks for reply. What I understand after reading about access logging, we create access logging group for API Gateway and write different log items `$context variables`. what is best tool to read, filter and render these logs in form of reports?